# Is it possible to have Firebase host your static Web site and another provider host your blog under the same domain?

Tags: wordpress, firebase, firebase-hosting

I recently began hosting my static site on Firebase, however I would like that site to also have a blog powered by Wordpress.

I'm wondering, if it's possible to configure Firebase to direct mysite.com/blog back to the my domain/hosting provider which supports PHP.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score -1):

If you have pointed your domain to Firebase, it is possible to have a Wordpress blog hosted by a separate hosting provider who supports PHP. However, you will need to use a subdomain such as blog.mydomain.com rather than a subdirectory such as mydomain.com/blog.

At least with my domain registrar, it is not currently possible to configure the DNS to point a subdirectory to the secondary host instead of Firebase once the domain itself is pointed to Firebase.

Comment: Which hosting do you think supports this?